# How to run cmd/shell commands from android studio programmatically?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have run the following lines of code and some similar solutions but nothing seems to work:

```
    StringBuilder cmdOut = new StringBuilder();
    Process process;
   try {
       process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell");
       InputStreamReader r = new 
       InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
       BufferedReader bfreader = new BufferedReader(r);
       char [] buf  = new char[4096];
       int nRead = 0;
       while((nRead = bfreader.read(buf)) > 0)
       {
           cmdOut.append(buf,0,nRead);
       }
       bfreader.close();
       try{
           process.waitFor();
       }
       catch (InterruptedException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


but when i run this i got the following error:I have looked after every answer but I have not found any working solution 

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied
```

If some one has any working solution please share it with example.

Comment: Consider using a shell script.

Comment: @RyanFleck Can you please elaborate more with any working example

Comment: Sure. Before I continue (only glanced at your question last time,) where are you trying to run this Java code? Is this part of a new plugin for android studio, OR are you trying to run this in your app, OR is this just a regular `.java` file on the command line?

Comment: I am working on an android app where on the click of the button i want commands "adb shell" and further such commands to execute.

Comment: Sure, but to run commands on your computer, you'll need to make a seperate application that runs on your desktop. You can't run **ADB** on your phone, because it doesn't have a copy of ADB.

Comment: Any way to do it by executing on server ?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to create an application with a REST API so your phone can connect to it and ask it (the desktop/server program) to call commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199428/discussion-between-ramandeep-singh-and-ryan-fleck).

Comment: Please go and complete the additional research required to complete your project, and mark the answer below as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute ADB directly from an android device.

You'll need to write a desktop application which executes the command and can be called by the android application, or (easier) use an [automation software](https://www.xda-developers.com/control-your-pc-from-your-android-device-with-tasker-part-1/) to call remote commands from your phone.